# Tabs navigation ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have already search lots to find solution, but no luck.

I need to redirect on different page when click on tab
My code:

in app.html

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="md-home" [root]="rootPage" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="md-person" [root]="profilePage" tabTitle="Profile"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="md-notifications" [root]="updatePage" tabTitle="Updates"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

in app.component.ts

```
rootPage: any = HomePage;
profilePage: any = ProfilePage;
updatePage: any = UpdatePage;
```

When i click on Home it's call homepage constructor, but did not redirect to home page.
suppose i'm on cart page and click on homepage Tab. it's call homepage constructor but page remains same.

Please help me. I'm ne in IONIC2

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the pages to app.modules.ts

```
entryComponents: [
   MyApp,
   HomePage,
   rootPage,profilePage,updatePage
],
```

and try to move the ion-tabs as root element, or inside ion-content

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-tabs tabbarPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab tabIcon="md-home" [root]="rootPage" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="md-person" [root]="profilePage" tabTitle="Profile"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="md-notifications" [root]="updatePage" tabTitle="Updates"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs> 
</ion-content>
```

change to tabbarPlacement attribute if you wish to place the control in the bottom.